# Is there a key binding to open the configuration file of Emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm going to set key binding to open and edit my `init.el`. Hotkey will call this function.

`(defun my-edit-configuration ()
  "Open the init file."
  (interactive)
  (find-file user-init-file))`

I wouldn't want to rewrite another standard key binding. What kind of a key binding usually utilized in Emacs for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard key binding to open the init file. There isn't really a standard keybinding for any function that isn't part of Emacs to begin with.

In general, the keybindings `C-c [a-z]` are reserved for users. That's control-c followed by an **unmodified letter**. `C-c C-[a-z]` may be used by major modes.

Answer (score 5):

Tyler's answer is right but there is a more specific way of remembering and accessing places in emacs and I recommend to use it instead of wasting your scarce reserved keybindings: bookmarks.

Use:

- `C-x r m` to bookmark a file.
- `C-x r b` to access a bookmark.
- `C-x r l` to list and edit bookmarks.

Now you know how to bookmark your `init.el`. Using `C-x r b` with, for example, ido-mode is a really fast way of accessing files and places.

Answer (score -1):

Before bind any key just check if it already bound: do `C-h k <and press hot key combination>`. It will describe hotkey if it signed.